# NestJS sequelize bulk insert

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I am new to nestJS and I am trying to insert bulk data. But I get the following error and I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong here. Some guidance would be highly appreciated.

[image]

stockStyle.entity.ts file:

```
import {
  Column,
  ForeignKey,
  Model,
  Table,
  HasMany,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { Stock } from '../stocks/entities/stock.entity';
import { Style } from '../styles/entities/style.entity';

@Table({ tableName: 'stock_style' })
export class StockStyle extends Model<StockStyle> {
  @ForeignKey(() => Stock)
  @Column
  stockId: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Style)
  @Column
  styleId: number;
}
```

stockStyle.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { StockStyle } from './v1/stockStyles/stockStyle.entity';

@Injectable()
export class StockStylesService {
  async bulkInsert() {
    const stockStyleArray = [
      { stockId: 'Diamond', styleId: 2 },
      { stockId: 'Gold', styleId: 2 },
      { stockId: 'Ruby', styleId: 2 },
    ];
    StockStyle.bulkCreate(stockStyleArray)
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the following way:

```
async bulkInsert() {
let holder: Array<StockStyle> = [];
const stockStyleArray = [
  { stockId: '1', styleId: 1 },
  { stockId: '2', styleId: 1 },
  { stockId: '3', styleId: 1 },
];
stockStyleArray.forEach((element) => {
  let stocks = new StockStyle();
  stocks.stockId = element.stockId;
  stocks.styleId = element.styleId;
  holder.push(stocks.get());
});
StockStyle.bulkCreate(holder);}
```

I don't know if this is a vaiable solution or not. I just used a workaround here. If anyone has a solution or better alternative to this, then please do free to share the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
  StockStyle.bulkCreate([ stockStyleArray])
```

I`m not sure, but you should try

```
  StockStyle.bulkCreate(stockStyleArray)
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo. But I am still getting the same error. And I have updated the typo in the question as well.